# How to submit form with enter key when I have a button, not a submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form with a button submit type, and I would like it to submit when enter key is pressed. I don't know how to implement this with the JS function I call when submitting the form.

FORM:

```
<form name="form1">
<textarea name="msg" id="message">
</textarea>
<p id="button">
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="submitChat()" id="innerbutton"></p>
```

JS Function

```
 function submitChat() {


    var uname = document.getElementById('nameplace').innerHTML

    var msg = form1.msg.value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var badname = uname.charAt(0); 

    if (msg != "" & badname != "<") {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','insert.php?uname='+uname+'&msg='+msg,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

Comment: check keycode on keydown event or change button type to submit, and add onsubmit=submitChat() on form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach `keydown` event with the document and call your function if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed

```
$(document).on("keydown",function(e){

   var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
   if(keyCode == 13) // enter key code
   {
      submitChat();
   }

});
```

Comment: Sorry, another thing. I have autofocus on as you can see, but now when I press enter, outofocus goes on to a new line. So each time a user enters a message, the cursor will go back to the text area BUT on a new line. How to prevent this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a real submit button and move your JavaScript from its click event to the form's submit event. Prevent the default behaviour of the form submission so that normal submission don't happen.

```
<form id="form1">
<textarea name="msg" id="message">
</textarea>
<p id="button">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</p>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", submitChat);

function submitChat(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById('innerbutton').onkeydown = function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
     // your submit function call here
   }
};
```

keyCode 13 is <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Hey @emre bolat , where should I put this? Thanks